# How to skip null values and solve error : Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How I can solve this error :

```
 Value cannot be null
```

this is the Model :

```
public class Orders_Tables
{
   // internal IQueryable<object> result { get; set; }
    public Lab_Orders  LabOrders { get; set; }
    public Lab_orders_Cash LabOrdersCash { get; set; }
    public Lab_Sample_status LabOrderStatus { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_RESULTS> LabResults { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestsRanges> testsRanges { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestsUnits>  testUnits { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_CULTURE_RESULT> LabCultureResults { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT> LabMicroResults { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LabTests> labtests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW> labClinicsViewResult { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LAB_RESULT_CASH_VIEW> labCashView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_PARASITOLOGY_VIEW> LabParasitologyView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_CULTURES_VIEW> LabCulturesView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_MICRO_VIEW> LabMicroView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_HISTOPATHOLOGY_VIEW> LabHistopathologyView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_HISTO_RESULT> LabHistoResult { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_PARA_RESULTS> LabParaResult { get; set; }

    public Lab_Hematology_Samples LabSamples { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LAB_URINE_ANALYSIS_RESULT> LabUrineResult { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LAB_URINE_RESULT_VIEW> LaburineView { get; set; }

  public Patients patients { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Customers> customers { get; set; }

}
```

This is the view I used the Model.order_table :

```
  @model IEnumerable<AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Clinics Orders";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Content/bootstrap.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Content/style.css")>
     <li><img width="500" height="100" style="margin-left:300px" src="~/Contents/images/mamlakaheader.png" />  <a href="~/Views/Orders/Clinicsorders.cshtml"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left:1200px"><a href=@Url.Action("Logout", "Login")><span class="d-inline-block bg-primary text-white btn btn-primary">Logout - تسجيل الخروج </span></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left:500px"> @Html.ActionLink("Welcome " + Session["UserFullname"], "Clinicsorders", "Orders") </li>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;color:coral;padding:10px;margin-left:500px">Orders List</h3>
    


<style> a {color: brown;text-decoration: wavy;text-shadow: 20px;font-size:medium;} a:hover {color: blue;}</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Clinicsorders", "Orders", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
    <div class="vertical-top">
        <span id="FromDate" style="margin-left:60px;color:red;font-size:large"><b>From Date</b></span><input id="FromDatetext" style="margin-left:10px" type="text" name="startdate" />
        <span id="ToDate" style="margin-left:95px;color:red;font-size:large"><b>To Date</b></span><input id="ToFatetext" type="text" style="margin:10px" name="enddate" /><br /><br />
      <span id="PCfileno" style="color:red;font-size:large"><b>Polyclinic File No</b></span><input id="PCFILENOTEXT" style="margin-left:10px" type="text" name="pcfileno" />
      <span id="IDNO" style="color:red;font-size:large;margin-left:30px"><b>ID or Iqama No</b></span><input id="idnotext" type="text" style="margin:10px" name="idno" />
      <span id="passport" style="color:red;font-size:large"><b>Passport No</b></span><input id="passporttext" style="margin-left:10px" type="text" name="Passport" />
      <span id="mobile" style="color:red;font-size:large;margin-left:30px"><b>Mobile No</b></span><input id="mobiletext" type="text" style="margin:10px" name="Mobile" />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-dark" />
    </div>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td> Patient Name </td>
        <td> Order No. </td>
        <td> Test Id</td>
        <td> order date    </td>
        <td> Polyclinic File </td>
        <td> Order Status   </td>


    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.patients.Patient_Name</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID</td>
            <!--Here is one-->
            <td>@(item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID.HasValue ? item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID : "No Test ID" )</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrders.ORDER_DATE</td>
            <td>@item.patients.PCfileNO</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrderStatus.status_name</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Result", "MasterDetails", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID },new { @class = "btn btn-primary" , target = "_blank" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Invoice", "Index", "Invoice", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target = "_blank" })</td>
            @if (item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID)
            {
           <!--Here is two (Do not render if TESTID has not a value)-->
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Culture Result", "download_culture", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID, testid = item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault().TESTID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target = "_blank" })</td>
            }
            @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("Culture Result", "download_culture", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID,testid = item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault().TESTID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target = "_blank" })</td>*@
        </tr>

        
        }
</table>
```

The error appeared on this line when I added TESTID

```
<td>@item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault().TESTID</td>
```

How to show TESTID if available and skip if null ?

This is the controller code :

```
 public ActionResult Clinicsorders(DateTime? startdate,DateTime? enddate, string pcfileno, string idno , string Passport , string Mobile)
        {

            int custId = (int)Session["UserCustid"];
            
            // eager load navigation properties
            // query is IQueryable
            var query = db.Lab_Orders.Where(r => r.CUSTID == custId)
                .Join(db.Lab_Sample_status, order => order.order_status, status => status.status_id, (order, status) => new { Order = order, Status = status })
                .Join(db.Patients, rec => rec.Order.patient_no, patient => patient.Patient_No, (rec, patient) => new Orders_Tables { LabOrders = rec.Order, LabOrderStatus = rec.Status, patients = patient });


            if (startdate.HasValue && enddate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LabOrders.ORDER_DATE) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate.Value) &&
                    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LabOrders.ORDER_DATE) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(enddate.Value));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pcfileno))
            {
                query = query.Where(r => r.patients.PCfileNO == pcfileno);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idno))
            {
                query = query.Where(r => r.patients.Patient_id == idno);
            }

         
            var model = query.OrderByDescending(r=>r.LabOrders.ORDER_ID).ToList();

            return View(model);
}
```

I need to make changes on the controller code and add the table , the orders table class include all the tables in one model together

Comment: Did you try "?." operator like this `@item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID`?

Comment: Does `item.LabCultureResults` have a value, or it *that* `null`?

Comment: @Batuhan I tried it but not working SAME ERROR

Comment: @HansKeﬆing not always has value

Comment: @MarwanAbu I added new answer please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault returns....default if it does not exist so dereferencing it will generate a nullreference exception

edit: extra if TESTID does not exist

@item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault().TESTID ?? "EMPTY"

A quick fix is to use the null coalescent operator ( ? )

```
@item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID ?? "EMPTY"
```

OR

```
@item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault() ?? "EMPTY"
```

Comment: I tried both solution but it show same error

Comment: I see, yeah TESTID can be non existing I see now. edited

Answer (score 1):

I catch another issue in your code. You have two accessors in page for `TESTID`. They marked on code below. You have to handle both accessors. May be your `item` or `LabOrders`is `null`. If not, the code below can does the job.

If condition depends on its own type.

For example if `TESTID` is int? you can use this:

`item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID.HasValue`

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td> Patient Name </td>
        <td> Order No. </td>
        <td> Test Id</td>
        <td> order date    </td>
        <td> Polyclinic File </td>
        <td> Order Status   </td>


    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.patients.Patient_Name</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID</td>
            <!--Here is one-->
            <td>@(item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID.HasValue ? item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID : "No Test ID" )</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrders.ORDER_DATE</td>
            <td>@item.patients.PCfileNO</td>
            <td>@item.LabOrderStatus.status_name</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Result", "MasterDetails", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID },new { @class = "btn btn-primary" , target = "_blank" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Invoice", "Index", "Invoice", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target = "_blank" })</td>
            @if(item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID.HasValue) 
            {
           <!--Here is two (Do not render if TESTID has not a value)-->
           <td>@Html.ActionLink("Culture Result", "download_culture", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID,testid = item.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault().TESTID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target = "_blank" })</td>
            }
       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: TESTID INT not string  there error cannot convert from int? to string

Comment: its not show the value TESTID column show this    ?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID

Comment: try adding `( )`: `<td>@(item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID)</td>`

Comment: thank you but there is errors in one : there is no implicit conversion between int? and string          and error in two : TESTID.HasValue : int does not contain a definition for HasValue

Comment: @MarwanAbu Can you add LabActionResults model to the question ? We can create condition logic much easier.

Comment: yes sure I updated the question added the model , view controller the relations between tables was ORDER_ID i need to pass TESTID to the view form table LabCultureResults

Answer (score 1):

Sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
List<string> LabCultureResults = null;

Console.WriteLine(LabCultureResults.Count); // (1)
Console.WriteLine(LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault()); // (2)
```

(1) throws the infamous NullReferenceException ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.").

(2) throws an ArgumentNullException with message "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')", because an extension method (like FirstOrDefault) *can* be called on a null value, but may decide not to accept it.

So your LabCultureResults is `null`.

When that Model is the result of an Entity Framework query, you need to `.Include(it => it.LabCultureResults)`.

Be aware that `FirstOrDefault()` may return a `null`, so don't just get the TESTID of the result - that will throw a NullReferenceException when the result is null. So use `item.LabCultureResults?.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID`.

Comment: thank you sir I updated the question where to make a link between LabOrders.ORDER_ID and  LabCultureResults.order_id ? note that only cultures orders will be there in labcultureresult table so I need to make leftjoin in a  query ?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the above answers:

Try:
`@item?.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID ?? ""`

Comment: I tried it but column value like this NewSite.Models.Orders_Tables?.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault()?.TESTID ?? ""    and testid not show